# where is the address that a function pointer stores

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I know that a function pointer stores the address of a function.

```
int fun(int x){
 //return something
} 
int (pfun*)(int)=&fun;

int main(){

std::cout << &fun << "\n"; // this print out 1
std::cout << fun << "\n" ; // this print out 1
std::cout << &pfun << "\n"; // this print out 0x0022ff40
std::cout << pfun << "\n" ; // this print out 1

 }
```

**So my questions are :** 
**1)** if the fun() doesn't even have an address how can pfun does point to fun().  
**2)** for example in dynamic binding when I use a pointer function at runtime. does the compiler change pfun value to a real pointer like 0X..... so that at runtime will know which function to call since the names doesn't existe after compilation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions `fun` and `&fun` have the same meaning: `&fun` which is equivalent to the value stored in `pfun`, so it is no wonder that the three of them yield the same output. `&pfun` is the address of the pointer, which is the address of the variable.

Now the question is why `1`... well, the answer is that there is no overloaded `operator<<` that takes an `std::ostream` and a function pointer, so the compiler tries to find the best match among the existing overloads which happens to be `bool` (a function pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`). The function pointer will be converted to `false` only if the function pointer is null, which is not the case. The `true` value is finally printed as `1` (you can check this by doing: `std::cout << std::boolalpha << fun` which will print `true`).

If you want to obtain the actual address of the function (in this process) you can force the cast to a void pointer and print the result. This might not be technically correct, but it will give you a number different than `1`... Note that the value might differ in different runs and basically has no meaning at all.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Casting of a function pointer to `void *` is not allowed. The standard explicitly says so, I think...Or was it specifically member function pointers, need to check..

Comment: @Als: that is the reason for the *not technically correct* comment in the answer. The fact is that IIRC it does work in most architectures, the standard does not guarantee it because some platforms in the past have had different pointer sizes for functions and data, which means that casting to `void*` and back to the original would not yield the original result... Then again, as I mentioned, even in the platforms where it does produce a value, it is useless.

Comment: Isn't the explicit mention of casting a function pointer to `void *` being invalid, only applicable to member function pointers? or even free standing function pointers?

Comment: @AlexDan: I am sorry, I don't really understand your comment. How does whatever I said conclude to *there is no difference between `fun` and `pfun`?* Also, I don't see no vtable involved that you are talking about.

Comment: @Als it's just a typo that question was not for you. sorry for that. you can answer this question if you want  why does the compiler uses function pointers inside vtable and not just simply use function names ?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : from what you've said, there is no difference between fun and pfun, since (void*)fun will also print out the same result as (void*)fun. whereas for example in vtable the compiler uses function pointers over function names, bcz names does not exit after compilation. I guess something must be wrong

Comment: @Als: Pointer to data<->pointer to code was the original reason to introduce `conditionally-supported` (1.3.5).

Comment: @AlexDan: The expression `fun` (i.e. the identifier that names the function) is translated to the address of the function (the translation happens between compilation, linking and process loading). Once the program is loaded into memory and the process start, there are no function names anywhere (other than the debug symbols to help debuggers understand the code). Also note that in vtables they are not regular functions but rather pointers to *member-function* s (big difference), and that in general the vtable might not even contain that, but a pointer to a *thunk* that adapts `this`.

Comment: In general *pointer* and *pointer-to-member* are completely different beasts, they might not have even the same size (a pointer to member that refers to a data member can be an offset from the beginning of the object, while a pointer to function member will depend on what the function is, if it is not virtual it might be a regular pointer, if it is a virtual function it can be an offset into the vtable to enable virtual dispatch... If you are interested in pointers to member functions, then you should ask about them, and not about regular pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

`operator<<` does not have an appropriate overload for printing function pointers. Try this instead.

```
#include <iostream>

void fun() {}

void (*pFun)() = &fun;

int main ()
{
  std::cout << (void*)pFun << "\n";
}
```